# iPhone iOS should mapkit based apps look like the iPhone native maps app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, mkmapview, appstore-approval

I'm building a map kit based app with a map view to display a list of pre-determined locations. I "borrowed" the look and feel of the maps app - the search bar with bookmarks list on top, the zoom to user location button in bottom left, the peel corner to reveal map type controls in bottom right.

To display a route to the map annotation, I'm opening the native maps app to plot the route.

**Is this kind of "maps app" like look and feel of the maps app encouraged, or am I violating some clause ?** I have not seen anything map specific in the app store review guidelines, but would like to make sure that I wont have any review trouble with my maps app.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html):

> **Important** The Map Kit framework uses Google services to provide map data. Use of the framework and its associated interfaces binds you to the Google Maps/Google Earth API terms of service. You can find these terms of service at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html.

In my experience, what you're doing is just fine as long as you don't obscure the google logo at the bottom of the map.

Answer (score 2):

What does your app *do*? If all it does is let users search places and get directions to them, then yeah you're blatantly ripping off the built-in app. But if this is a small part of your app, and it does a bunch of other things with original UI, then sure - why not present the user with a familiar UI paradigm? It all depends on what your app does, and how much of it you're copying from other apps, and for what scenarios.

Comment: Thank you! The map feature is just a small part of the app, so I guess it's fine to present a familiar interface